# ASP.NET Application_Error Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, maxrequestlength

I have a web application and users started uploading large files. To avoid errors i did this:

1- Set the httpRuntime maxRequestLength.
2- Edited the Application_Error function of Global.asax to this:

```
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
                return;
```

It all works well when i have fiddler on, and the user gets redirected to the same page.
But if fiddler is off the browser shows this:

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you are getting correct url using Request.RawUrl. In line: Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);

it seems page is redirected to the same page again and again, try to find using debug statement.

Comment: What do you intend with this redirection? And why are you dealing with Application_Error if you are trying to "avoid" error? Do you intend to mask it?

Comment: Ashwini/Anderson - There is no cycle. The user makes an oversize POST and i intend to redirect him to the same page (GET) and show a error message instead of a ugly error